# Extra content at the end of the document - XML

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the XML code that I've made

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?aa a=100 b="123"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog_client.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE bookstore [
  <!ELEMENT bookstore (book)>
  <!ELEMENT book (title,author)>
  <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
]>
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" price="18">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Juan Tamad</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" price="22">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
  </book>
  <!-- Processing instruction PI's -->
  <?bb a=100 b="123"?>
  <book genre="philosophy" price="20">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy" price="20">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>
      <![CDATA[Juan<a>&Pedro</a>]]>
      </first-name>
    </author>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

and this is the XSL file that's in the same directory with the XML file above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <h2>Library Books</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Author</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open the XML file it says **error on line 1 at column 23: Extra content at the end of the document**

I tried to look at the code again and I cannot find typo

Why is it saying this? Need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml needs a root element

```
<h2>Library Books</h2>
<table border="1">

</table>
```

Try adding e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
<!-- .... -->
</div>
</xsl:template>
```